# SQL Match All Values from Left Table to Groups of Right Table

Tags: sql, join, group-by, left-join

I have two tables - 'LeftTable' and 'RightTable'. The data in these look like these:

LeftTable

```
T1 | C45  
T1 | C46  
T1 | C47
```

RightTable

```
T9 | C45  
T9 | C47  
T10| C45  
T10| C46  
T10| C47  
T10| C52
```

I am trying to write a SQL query that tells me the which 'T' entries from the right table contains all 'C' entries in it as are in the LeftTable

The LeftTable only has one kind of 'T' entry. So, because LeftTable has C45, C46, C47 - I want the 'T' values from RightTable which have corresponding 'C's as C45 C46 C47.

Hence, in this case, it should return T10 (which has all three). However, it should not return T9 (as it has only two common 'C' values from LeftTable)

Comment: Have you made an attempt at this yet?  It's a pretty simple outer join or `EXISTS` operation.

Comment: @JNK - Isn't it actually a `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` clause?  How would you do it with `EXISTS`?

Comment: It looks simple but isn't simple. 
Here's why you can't use GROUP BY - because you are not using any Aggregate function. So that fails

Comment: The EXISTS doesn't give correct results as well.. because EXISTS on RT will scan the entire right table and you can't do a group by Table EXISTS operation.
If you do a exists on LT, you can't again.. do a FOREACH kind of thing on RT

Comment: The problem here is it is a many to many relationship where each C-field from LT can be present for more than one T-field in RT. And each T-field from RT can (and should) have more than one C-field from LT

Answer (score 0):

The question is more interesting than I first thought. :-)

Assuming that there is a combined unique key on RightTable (rt) this would work:

```
select rt.id , count(*) right_count 
from rt join lt on rt.val=lt.val 
group by rt.id
having count(*) = (select count(distinct val) from lt)
```

with:

rt = RightTable

lt = LeftTable

id = T-field

val = C-field

I hope this helps.
Ralph

Comment: Hi Ralph,
That's a close call. I see you are verifying the inclusion through matching counts of T-fields for each C-field. That may work in some cases while it may fail in other cases when the count is same but values within are different.

Comment: Hi Akash, yes - that's my opening assumption (combined unique key on rt.id+rt.val).

Comment: And I do an inner join between right- and left-table. So there can't be false positives. If the combined unique constraint is given, this works 100%. Else I wouldn't see a way to do it without coding a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Need something like this:

SELECT T-Value FROM RT

WHEN

(SELECT C-VALUEs FROM LT EXIST IN
   (SELECT C-VALUEs FROM RT for each t-value)
)